# href="#" appends # on end of page url

Tags: javascript, html, url, hyperlink

Let's say I have the following link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('You clicked a link.');">Click Me!</a>
```

When clicked this link will alert a message as well as appending a pound sign on the end of the page url. 
This doesn't look very pretty is there any way to avoid it besides using javascript in the url itself:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('You clicked a link.');">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is `return false` on the event handler.

```
<a href="" onclick="alert('You clicked a link.'); return false">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: You must give a non-empty href to the link, because IE6,7 wouldn't recognize it as such, so # would be ok as a href, as long as you keep return false; in the onclick.

Comment: @bisko Wow.. really? Even though an empty string is a valid URI?

Comment: Even better, give a real value for href - I.e. Something that actually returns a page if JavaScript is disabled or otherwise not working.

Comment: @bradley yes. It's a secret that IE6,7 complies fully with the standarts :) </sarcasm> Yes, IE6,7 have this problem. I'm not sure for 8 and above. When you don't specify a href, the A behaves just a normal span :)

Comment: @Tom See http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#same-document and http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#path (the last link gives ABNF if the first is ambiguous)

Comment: I just tested `href=""` in IE6 and it works fine, perhaps you're confusing that with omitting the href attribute completely? (which does indeed make the element no longer a hyperlink)

Answer (score 6):

You have to prevent the default response from occurring.

The old-fashioned approach is to `return false` from it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('You clicked a link.'); return false;">Click Me!</a>
```

Or, better:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Click Me!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = function(event) {
      alert('You clicked a link.');
      return false;
   };
};
</script>
```

The best approach nowadays is to call the proper method of the `event` property:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Click Me!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = function(event) {
      alert('You clicked a link.');
      event.preventDefault(); // <---
   };
};
</script>
```

It's also best to replace that `#` with an URI to some proper page, for people not using JavaScript. In some jurisdictions, accessibility is in fact a *legal requirement*.

**Edit** Fixed for bleedin' IE:

```
function f() {
   document.getElementById('myLink').onclick = function(e) {
      alert('You clicked a link.');

    if (!e) {
       var e = window.event;
    }

    // e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue  = false;

    // e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

window.onload = f;
```

Comment: Could you give more explanation on why this is better than my approach?

Comment: @bradley.ayers: (a) Separates flow from format. Inline JS is evil. (b) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357146#1357146 is why `event.preventDefault()` is preferred. (c) As I indicated, using a real URI is a legal requirement, and an obvious aid to users.

Comment: the 'best approach method' won't work in IE as they use `window.event`

Comment: @qwertymk: Thanks; have incorporated a fix.